# How to disable wrapping pasted text in search line

Tags: vim

I got "additional" functionality either from vim or some plugin. Recently I updated vim to 8.0.216 and updated all my plugins. The "additional" functionality I get is when I search for string in a file with `/` and paste, for example *"term"*, the resulted pasted text become `<PasteStart>term<PasteEnd>`.

How can I disable this annoying functionality?

I tried to disable all my plugins and removed `.vimrc` completely, but the wrapping is still there. Is this something new build to vim?

Edit:
I use iTerm2. Tried in buit-in terminal - its the same.
I saw somewhere this is related with tmux. Removed tmux and loaded fresh console. Same.
I am using oh-my-zsh if this could be related.

Edit2
I use shortcut commands for both copy and paste.

Comment: start vim with `vim -u NONE` from terminal , still same? How do you "paste"?

Comment: This has to be an `iTerm2`-caused behavior. I was looking at vim's sourc and it simply translates an special sequence `K_PS` to that text. Also, I could avoid this behavior with "Special Paste..." menu by unselecting the "Bracketed paste mode"... I haven't find how to make it default.

Comment: @Kent Yes, still the same. I use command + v to paste. I have easyclip plugin and this setting https://github.com/kdelchev/dotfiles/blob/master/dotfiles/vimrc#L230

Comment: @kode ok from memoselyk's comment, it could be the Apple/mac specific problem.... no experience with mac.

Comment: @kode It might be a zsh issue, please 1, try a different shell, 2, start zsh with `unset zle_bracketed_paste` and comment your results

Comment: @memoselyk tried advanced paste. It works, but cant make it default. Didnt found such option in iterm settings.

1. Tried starting `bash` them fire up `vim` and the paste behaves the same.
2. in `zsh` run `unset zle_bracketed_paste`, then fire up `vim` and paste behaves the same.

Comment: @kode I'm sorry, I observed a different behavior with a bash session I had, so I assumed it could be a possible solution. It turned out that bash was still using _Vim 7.4_ due to executable caching. I can confirm, this is a new _Vim 8.0_ behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found three possible workarounds:

1, Use iTerm's `Paste special` and uncheck the `Bracketed paste mode`. Unfortunately, that's 3 extra clicks.

2, Use the [Bracketed paste](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/vim-bracketed-paste) plugin, or add the relevant commands to your `.vimrc`:

```
execute "set <f28>=\<Esc>[200~"
execute "set <f29>=\<Esc>[201~"
cmap <f28> <nop>
cmap <f29> <nop
```

3, Create an alternate shortcut to paste with `Bracketed paste mode` disable:

> 1. Go to prefs>keys
> 2. Click the +
> 3. Select the keyboard shortcut field and press **⌘⌥v**
> 4. For Action, select Paste…
> 5. Select the desired options. E.g. Disable `Bracketed paste mode`.
> 6. Press ok

[Source](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues/3362) of alternative shorcut.

NOTE: You could simply re-bind the Command + V.

Comment: Nice. 1 - no way to use this as vim user :) 2 - sounds weird to add plugin to do a normal paste. 3 - works great as a workaround. I remapped command+v to do just normal paste without this bracket weirdness. Thanks for the hints! Very extensive answer.

Comment: I see this for vim everywhere. I am having this issue with just iTerm, copying from my editor(VSCode) I get extra stuff. From what I could find, it's related to the bracketed paste mode. I followed these steps and the problem still persists.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: update your Vim.

[Apparently it's a bug](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_use/GuYDsQTlRLA/JLo1kksrAQAJ) and updating Vim (to 8.0.0237) has solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Upgrading also worked for me. I +1 your answer, but will leave the @memoselyk's answer accepted, since it helped me at the time. PS: the link reference is also good.